# unable to insert child element in XML from actionscript3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I am trying to insert child node in xml via actionscript as follow -

```
var xml:XML = <menu>
<item>burger</item>
<item>soda</item>       
</menu>;
xml.insertChildAfter(xml.item[0], <item>fries</item>);
trace(xml);
----------output---------------
<menu>
  <item>burger</item>
  <item>fries</item>
  <item>soda</item>
</menu>
-------------------------
```

the above code is working fine as expected, but when i am trying to insert a child in nested child, i am unable to insert.

but below is not working-

```
var xml:XML = <menu>
<my>
<item>burger</item>
<item>soda</item>
</my>
</menu>;
xml.insertChildAfter(xml.my.item[0], <item>fries</item>);
trace(xml);
------------output-------------
<menu>
  <my>
    <item>burger</item>
    <item>soda</item>
  </my>
</menu>
```

---

moreover it returns `undefined` and as described in actionscript livedocs -

```
If you call this method on an XML child that is not an element (text, attributes, comments, pi, and so on) undefined is returned.
```

any help/input  is greatly appreciated, thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of `insertChildAfter` must be a direct child of the XML node you are calling the method on. So try:

```
var xml:XML = <menu>
<my>
<item>burger</item>
<item>soda</item>
</my>
</menu>;
xml.my.insertChildAfter(xml.my.item[0], <item>fries</item>);
trace(xml.toXMLString());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It works, too.

```
var xml:XML = <menu>
                <my>
                    <darling>
                        <item>burger</item>
                        <item>soda</item>
                    </darling>
                </my>
            </menu>;
xml..*::darling.insertChildAfter(xml..*::darling.item[0], <item>fries</item>);
trace(xml);
-------output------------------
<menu>
  <my>
    <darling>
      <item>burger</item>
      <item>fries</item>
      <item>soda</item>
    </darling>
  </my>
</menu>
```